# Using position: absolute to vertically align top navigation items

Tags: html, css

I'm building a top navigation bar. I'd like the logo & menu items on the right to be vertically centered. To achieve this, I'm looking to set the position of the container of both logo & menu items as relative, and then set the position of logo & menu items as absolute to achieve the effect.

This successfully worked for the logo. However, it's not working for menu items, in fact, all the menu items are gone once the code below is implemented. Not sure what's going on here.

```
<div class="boxA">

<div class="box1">
  <div class="site">
    <a href=""><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
  </div> 
</div>

<div class="box2">
<nav class="menu"> 
  <ul>
      <li><a href="">menu1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">menu2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">menu3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">menu4</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>

</div>



    
.boxA:after {
  content:"";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.boxA {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E0DCDC;
}

.boxA img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 3%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.box2 li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}


.box1 {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
}

.box2 {
  float: right;
  width: auto;
}




.box2 ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;  
}


.box2 li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none; 
  font-size: 12px;
}

.box2 li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.box2 ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.box2 li {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
}


.box1 img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to create a [mcve] in a snippet?  As it is, I don't really know how to recreate your issue in order to debug it.

Comment: Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zbcawm2j/  Something wrong with this code: .box2 li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}   the menu items disappear once implemented. I'm looking to vertically center menu items (as they often are in top nav bar)  Ps. Fiddle has the same code as OP as I felt I need most of it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
body{margin:0}

.boxA {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background: #b6d6f3;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #8ac8ff;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px 5px;
}
.site img {
    width: 100px;
}
.menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxA">

        <div class="box1">
          <div class="site">
            <a href=""><img src="https://www.smashingmagazine.com/images/smashing-cat/cat-with-slippers.svg"></a>
          </div> 
        </div>

        <div class="box2">
        <nav class="menu"> 
          <ul>
              <li><a href="">menu1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">menu2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">menu3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">menu4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        </div>
</div>
```

Try not to use css `float` property instead use [css grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) or [css flex box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

#### EDIT 1 :

If you want to see the same result in IE without using `flex` property then.

```css
.boxA:after {
  content:"";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.boxA {
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E0DCDC;
}

.boxA img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 3%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

.box2 ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);

  /* -- NEW -- */
  right: 10px;
}


.box1 {
  float: left;

  /* -- NEW -- */
  width: 100PX;
  background-color: #cddef7;
  height: 100px;
}

.box2 {
    float: right;
    /* -- NEW -- */
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #85c3f9;
    height: 100px;
}

.box2 ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;  
}


.box2 li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none; 
  font-size: 12px;
  /* --NEW-- */
  padding:2px 0;
}

.box2 li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.box2 ul:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* DOES NOT REQUIRED--
.box2 li {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
}
*/


.box1 img {
  position: absolute;
  /* --NEW-- */
  width:80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxA">

        <div class="box1">
          <div class="site">
            <a href=""><img src="https://www.smashingmagazine.com/images/smashing-cat/cat-with-slippers.svg"></a>
          </div> 
        </div>

        <div class="box2">
        <nav class="menu"> 
          <ul>
              <li><a href="">menu1</a></li>
              <li><a href="">menu2</a></li>
              <li><a href="">menu3</a></li>
              <li><a href="">menu4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Why do you recommend not using float? I was using float (vs. flexbox) to make the site work on Internet Explorer

Comment: because `float` does some bad things. To remove those bad behaviours standard invented flexbox and grid to overcome from this.

Comment: I see. Per your recommendation - does this mean that compatibility with Internet Explorer just isn't a thing that developers need to worry about in general?

Comment: It is good to target all kind of people (generally who use IE). So you have to code also for browser compatible. Visit [hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/) they are using `flexbox` on the header. So first try to inspect the header in modern browser then visit same site again in IE and then again use inspector to see differences. (are you getting me ?)

Comment: It is our personal choice to support or not to support IE. _Example => If you're building an online shopping website then I think you must have to worry about all of your users (modern + who use IE)_. Read [this](https://medium.com/front-end-field-guide/do-i-need-to-worry-about-internet-explorer-in-2017-c46657a0fd08) article and clear your doubts.

Comment: While I appreciate that it is a case-by-case consideration for whether to support IE, it is worth noting that Microsoft itself is no longer maintaining IE and trying to sunset it entirely and move users to Edge.  Also, legacy browser support is of course dependent upon several considerations, but two that sometime get excluded: cost (for instance, if legacy browser users spend $100K on your site each year but it costs $102K to maintain compatible code it may not be worth it) and whether the IE traffic you measure on your site is real, or largely your own testers using that browser.